# Запуск pyhon script на apache2 server on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: python, ubuntu

Есть бот на питоне и vps server с ubuntu. Как запустить мой скрипт и сделать так, чтобы он перезапускался, если возникает ошибка в скрипте?

Comment: Автозапуск программ в linux регулирует система инициализации (например, `systemd` в Ubuntu), таймеры можно настраивать с помощью `cron` или того же `systemd` (timer units).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно запускать python script через [Gunicorn](https://gunicorn.org/), а сам Gunicorn запускать при помощи [Supervisor](http://supervisord.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Скрипт стоит запускать через [Supervisor](https://www.8host.com/blog/ustanovka-i-upravlenie-supervisor-na-servere-ubuntu-i-debian/)(инструкция по ссылке).